# prestashop quantity not set using object mobel

Tags: php, prestashop

I'm setting the product quantity using the following code:

```
$stock = (int)$prod->stock;
$ObjProduct->quantity = $stock;
$ObjProduct->out_of_stock = 0;
```

When I go to the back office, the quantity of every product is set to 0. No errors are thrown during execution of the php script, and echoing out the value of $stock shows that values are being returned as expected. I've also tried passing in the quantity as a string.

Any idea whats going on here?

Comment: You might want to include the class definition for the `$ObjProduct` class to widen your responses beyond those who are familiar with Prestashop.  Right now you are not even indicating what class it is such that is one even wanted to go look at the code for prestashop they would know where to look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to update the stock

```
StockAvailable::setQuantity($prod->id_product, 0, (int) $prod->stock);
```